# Creating a tag - What badges or reputation do I get?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, badges

So I just **created my first tag** (applause not necessary), and I see more and more users following it.

My simple question is: 
As the tag creator, does it somehow increase my **reputation**? Are there any **badges** related to this?

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not increase your reputation.

What will increase your reputation is if you create a tag wiki and/or excerpt, and they get Approved.

There is also the [Taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), if the tag gets used by 50 or more questions. You usually get that one when you least expect it.